# Turning thousands of elements from a light curve disk into an array

Tags: arrays, element, idl-programming-language

I am a bit new to this, and have been assigned something quite simple. However, I can't seem to get the job done.

I'm working on light curves for a research product and the data has up to 10,000 elements (sometimes more). My professor asked me to simply turn all these elements into an array with n-elements of dimension so that when we print the data, all 10,000 elements are not loading and we can just call the element we want from the array.

How do I go about approaching this? Feel free to ask for more clarification!

[The data file that I call given my prof's routine called ldsk; it tells me how big the file is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Kud.png)

Comment: Are we talking about Interface Description Language, or Interactive Data Language?  The former is the association with the tag [tag:idl], while the latter uses tag [tag:idl-programming-language]

Answer (score 0):

> My professor asked me to simply turn all these elements into an array with n-elements...

Let me use the variables `ej` for the j-th element of an array.  Assume each of your ~10,000 values corresponds to a different element, `ej`, then you can create the array doing the following:

```
array = [e1, e2, e3, e4, ..., eN]
```

where N = ~10,000 and the `...` was used to avoid having to type out 10,000 terms.  Does that make more sense?

Make sure you use []'s in [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_(programming_language)), not ()'s to create arrays.  Newer versions under different compiling options can mistake the ()'s for the calling of a function.

> we can just call the element we want from the array.

Once created, you can index the array and print to the screen using the following (assume you want the j-th element):

```
PRINT, array[j]
```

where `j` can be any number between `1` and `N - 1` (since IDL starts indexing from zero).

Comment: Is there a less tedious way of typing out 10,000 elements to name a new array? I can't imagine a data file having hundreds of thousands of elements and having to create an array by single-handedly typing in every single element from the data file.

Comment: @s.amir - In what format is the data currently?  How is the data being created?  If it is the output of a function, then you can assign the indices of a dummy array to each call of the function.  I would need more info before answering your question.

Comment: so the data has already been collected and is in a file that i call up given the routines the professor has already created: I just put a screenshot of it up in my original question. The data is in a file called Kepler-0.dsk.

Comment: What does the routine `ldsk` do?  When you run that routine, does it create pointers or something?  How are you getting data into IDL?